# Share "actions/cache@v3" cached files across tags and branches

Tags: github, github-actions

Even when using only a cache key, which is the hash of my dependencies plus the operating system or target (as in the case of WebAssembly running on Ubuntu), I'd like to know if it's possible for `actions/cache` to share the cache across **tags and branches** instead of creating one per each. To me, it doesn't make sense, since I'm already caching by the hash.

If yes, how can I do this? My builds last more than 30 minutes without the cache, making it totally unfeasible to use GitHub Actions.

```
- name: Cache Dependencies
  uses: actions/cache@v3
  with:
    path: |
      ~/.conan2/p
      ~\.conan/p
    key: ${{ matrix.config.name }}-${{ hashFiles('**/conanfile.txt') }}
    restore-keys: ${{ matrix.config.name }}-
```

[image]

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows#restrictions-for-accessing-a-cache